# Parent folder inheriting Child sub-folder or file attributes without creating a new folder and copying

Tags: powershell, vbscript, timestamp

Is there a way to change the folder time and date (the attribute properties) via a DOS Batch file, VBS, PERL or a Powershell script?

Example:

FOLDER: F1, F2, F3...
SUB-FOLDER: S1, S2, S3 ...
FILES: L1, L2.....Ln

Say the current time on folders, sub-folders and files is like this:

```
Jan-01-2000 1:00AM
```

Then I add a new sub-folder called `S7` with time `Jan-01-2001 23:00PM`

This should automatically cause the top folder (`F1`) to have attribute properties copied from the latest file (or sub-folder) time stamp. That means the `F1` folder should be now `Jan-01-2001 23:00PM` from `Jan-01-2000 1:00AM` because it now inherits the time/date attributes from `S7`.

Is a VB, VBS, Powershell Script, or Batch file doable?

Comment: Possible? Certainly. Worth the effort, well that would be up to you and why you think you need to do this. There are two methods that immediately come to mind. The first is to have a scheduled task that runs every hour or so. The task would get all the subfolders and sort them by LastWriteTime. Then it would grab the date from the most recent and set the parent folder's LastWriteTime to that. The second method would be to register a WMI event synce that would essentially do the same thing any time anything was added to the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell can walk through a folder and find the latest written file/folder. You can then use it to set it for the folder.

```
$Path = 'c:\temp'

(Get-Item $Path).LastWriteTime = (Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending)[0].LastWriteTime
```

You can save the above code and run it periodically using Task Scheduler or by using a file monitoring tool to trigger it.